# How can I explicitly say what an associated type should be?

Tags: rust, type-hinting, associated-types

I have a trait which is something like `Iterator`, and a wrapper around it:

```
pub struct Wrapped<I: Iterator>(I);
```

Many of the functions on wrapped iterators return new wrapped iterators using `impl-trait`.

```
impl <I: Iterator> Wrapped<I> {
  pub fn foo(self) -> Wrapped<impl Iterator<Item=Foo<I::Item>>> {...}
  pub fn bar(self) -> Wrapped<impl Iterator<Item=Bar<I::Item>>> {...}
}
```

so that after a while, it becomes easy for the user to lose track of what the iterator item is in the calling code (eg. for expressions like `my_wrapped.foo().bar().bar().foo()`).

I'd like to give the user a way to explicitly specify what type they expect the `Item` to be such that if it's not that type then there's a compile-time error:

```
let y = x.foo().bar().bar().foo().assert_item_type::<Foo<Bar<Bar<Foo<X>>>>>()
```

but so far, the only way I've found to do this is a bit weird and ugly. Is there a cleaner way?

```
pub trait Is {
    type Myself;
}

impl<T> Is for T {
    type Myself = T;
}

impl <I: Iterator> Wrapped<I> {
    pub fn assert_item_type<Item: Is<Myself = I::Item>>(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that your approach is as clean as it gets, aside from using a generic extension trait instead of an inherent impl on `Wrapped`. You can't use `=` outside of associated types (for now, I believe), so the `Is` trait is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a free-standing function, you can employ a similar approach without the need for any traits:

```
fn assert_item_type<I: Iterator<Item=T>, T>(x: Wrapped<I>) -> Wrapped<I> {
    x
}


let y = assert_item_type::<_, Foo<Bar<Bar<Foo<X>>>>>(x.foo().bar().bar().foo());
```

Unfortunately it is [currently not possible](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83701) to replace the `I` type parameter in `assert_item_type` with an `impl Iterator` (which would get rid of the underscore in the turbofish) as the compiler [does not allow us](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71869) to provide explicit generic arguments when `impl Trait` is used in argument position.

If and when this feature is introduced in the compiler, the function can then (hypothetically) be defined and used as:

```
fn assert_item_type<T>(x: Wrapped<impl Iterator<Item=T>>) -> Wrapped<impl Iterator<Item=T>> {
    x
}


let y = assert_item_type::<Foo<Bar<Bar<Foo<X>>>>>(x.foo().bar().bar().foo());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1a3ea56fed4742e815e1d8572b10208)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like non-goal for an API. Instead, can't the user rely on typical impl trait syntax in their own code to accomplish this task?

e.g.

```rust
struct X;

fn accept_iterator(it: impl Iterator<Item = X>) { ... }

fn main() {
    let complex_iterator = x.foo().bar().foo().bar()...;
    // Will only compile if `complex_iterator` is an iterator of `X`s
    accept_iterator(complex_iterator);
}
```

While it isn't a dedicated method for this task, it accomplishes what you desire in a more idiomatic way.